# Symfony2 and angularjs bootstrap directive, how to find templates

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap Angularjs directives with Symfony2 and assetic.

But as I want to compile the files, Bootstrap directives are not able to find templates.

After some hacks (add a slash before the templates url in the js file and create a symlink) I find templates, but I have a [strange error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Ftabs%2Ftab.html).
So is there a good method to use bootstrap directives with Symfony2 ?

I work with the [Angular Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/sunra/angularjs-symfony2-bundle)
and the file: bootstrap-gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.min.js
Thank you in advance for your help.